# Visual FoxPro 9 dynamic Arrays

Tags: arrays, dynamic, com, visual-foxpro

I'm trying to get Dynamic Arrays from my ActiveX component trough Visual FoxPro 9, but with no luck. **(Edited and Working example)**

```
LOCAL objMain, objAdapt

#define CrLf CHR(13) + CHR(10)

stMsg = ""

objMain = CREATEOBJECT('nnetsdk.oMain')

objMain.UnlockComponent("xxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xx")

objAdapt = CREATEOBJECT('nnetsdk.oNetworkAdapter')

objAdapt.GetNetworkAdapters && Collects Network Adapter information

vrAdapters = objAdapt.cName && cName holds collected Network Adapter names

FOR EACH vrAdapter IN vrAdapters
 stMsg = stMsg + vrAdapter + CrLf
ENDFOR

MESSAGEBOX(stMsg,64,"List Network Adapters")

RELEASE objAdapt
RELEASE objMain
```

Can someone explain me what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your "nnetcom.oMain" ActiveX control is, but you can get directly from VFP via

```
lcComputerName = "."
loWMIService = GETOBJECT("winmgmts:\\" + lcComputerName + "\root\cimv2")
loItems = loWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter",,48)

FOR EACH loItem IN loItems
    lcMACAddress = loItem.MACAddress
    IF !ISNULL(lcMACAddress)
        */ then, you can look at the object properties, such as 
        lcDescription = loItem.Description
        lcMacAddress = loItem.MACAddress
        lcNetConnectionID = NVL( loItem.NetConnectionID, "" )
   ENDIF
ENDFOR
```

the For Each loop cycles through class instances of the [Win32_NetworkAdapter] class structure.  You can get almost anything you want from that list.
[1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi DRapp, Yes, I know the WMI, in fact my ActiveX component uses it. The **objAdapt.cName** holds the collected network adapter names in Array.

Comment: @beic, then I guess I'd be curious why using an ActiveX control when VFP can get it and process an array directly too.

Comment: Yes, but I developing a sort of Framework component...anyway, you helped me a lot with that line of code **FOR EACH loItem IN loItems**, now its working perfectly...I upvoted you proposition and accepted as an Answer! Thanks... ;-) p.s. I will add the corrected example to my post!